# Textmate error duplicating lines "ruby: warning: -K is specified; it is for 1.8 compatibility and may cause odd behavior"

Tags: ruby, duplicates, warnings, textmate

While using ctrl+shift+d to shortcut to duplicate lines in Textmate, I came to the following error:

"ruby: warning: -K is specified; it is for 1.8 compatibility and may cause odd behavior"

Answer (score 4):

This problem isn't limited to duplicating lines, but shows up in may other places where ruby is used. I solved it by changing `PATH` at `Preferences… > Advanced > Shell Variables` to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

After this change, TextMate will use the older version of `ruby` which doesn't output said warnings.

Answer (score 3):

This is an output warning from ruby 2.0 .

The only way I could solve it was by going to

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions and changing the symlink named Current to point to the folder 1.8 ( /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8 ) .

In other words, changed back to use ruby 1.8 instead of 2.0 .

Comment: Is it your own answer?

Comment: I had this problem and I didn't find anyone to have experienced it, so I decided to put it here, in case someone else runs into it.

Comment: Have you been confised by the warning?

Comment: Not confused. Textmate was adding the warning text to my document, every time I tried to duplicate a line.
I.E.:
if I had a line with:

x = 1;

When I tried to duplicate it, it would show:

x = 1;ruby: warning: -K is specified; it is for 1.8 compatibility and may cause odd behavior

Comment: but `-Kkcode` for ruby is just for codepage specification, what does it cause to the line duplication?

Comment: I'm not sure. AFAIK Texmate calls a ruby script to do the line string duplication. The fact is that it was showing it, and this was the only way I knew to fix it.

Comment: So I think the better way is to find out where textmate stores call keys to run *ruby* interpreter, and remove the `-Kkcode`, or if available, to close the call under conditional `if` instead of it.

Comment: I had the same issue. this fixed it for me

Comment: I knew it would be of help to someone some day :)